# Inserir filtro dinamico em uma angularjs expression

Tags: angularjs

Estou tentando inserir um filtro dinâmico de acordo com um campo de um objeto no `ng-grid`. Tentei de vários jeitos e não consegui:

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { displayName: 'entity.tipoPessoa', field: 'tipoPessoa'},
    { displayName: 'entity.id', field: 'id', cellTemplate: '<div class=\"ngCellText\" ng-class=\"col.colIndex()\"><span ng-cell-text>[Insira o trecho de código aqui]</span></div>'},
    //...
]:
```

Trecho de código:

```
{{ row.entity.tipoPessoa == "F" ? row.entity.id | brCpf : row.entity.id | brCnpj }}

{{ row.entity.tipoPessoa == "F" ? "row.entity.id | brCpf" : "row.entity.id | brCnpj" }}

{{ row.entity.tipoPessoa == "F" ? "{{row.entity.id | brCpf}}" : "{{row.entity.id | brCnpj}}" }}

{{ row.entity.tipoPessoa == "F" ? {{row.entity.id | brCpf}} : {{row.entity.id | brCnpj}} }}
```

Nenhum desses jeitos funcionaram. Qual a maneira certa de se fazer? Devo tentar outra abordagem?

Comment: Angular não suporta o operador `?`. Utilize um `span` com `ngIf`. Os filtros `brCpf`, etc, estão definidos e funcionando corretamente em um caso simples? Qual erro obtido? O que era esperado? Algum erro no console?

Comment: Não havia erro no console, mas ele apresentava a string (row.entity.id | brCpf) e não "a executava".

Answer (score 2):

Resolvi criando um `custom filter`, com certeza deve haver outra forma de se fazer, mas deixo aqui a solução utilizada:

```
app.filter('CpfCnpj', ['$filter', function($filter) {
    return function(CpfCnpj) {
        var cpfSize = 11;
        return CpfCnpj.length <= cpfSize ? $filter('brCpf')(CpfCnpj) : $filter('brCnpj')(CpfCnpj);
    };
}]);
```